# Parallel resistor in pi filter

Tags: filter

What is the purpose of resistor in this filter circuit? Is it really needed?
[image]

Comment: A pi filter fundamentally matches an impedance on one side to an impedance on the other port so, if the circuit is truly a pi filter (and just because it looks like one doesn't mean it is) then there may be relevance to that resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one (or many ) of three things

1. damping resistor associated with the 2nd order system that has been created. The Q factor of the LC could be quite high and it can cause quite large amplitude signals at the resonant frequency. This R will provide a damping term
2. bleed resistor for when the circuit is disconnected. this is either for safety or to ensure that some downstream threshold monitor (UVLO) is activated again if there is a momentary blackout
3. base load to some upstream PSU. Some PSU have a minimum load requirement and a simple resistor is sometimes effective enough in providing a minimum load

Without seeing the wider circuit and use-case information, it is hard to assess beyond this

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell whether it's really needed just from the small part of the overall schematic of a complex device you're showing. Chances are, someone put it there for a reason!

I can only speculate, but 4.7 uF is really a pretty big capacitor. Maybe they wanted to add a "bleed" resistor so that the capacitor safely discharges while not in use. Maybe the whole signal chain is AC-coupled, but should be (weakly) pulled to oscillate around GND.